# Once i added browserRouter it is showing me an empty page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have downloaded everything and it is not showing or displaying anything on the page. Here is the error that is showing in the inspect

[image]

Here is the code
This is App.js

```
//import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter , Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <header>
          <a href="/">VAC</a>
        </header>
        <main>
          <Routes>
          <Route  path="/" element={<HomeScreen/>}/>
          </Routes>
        </main>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is HomeScreen.js

```
import data from '../data';
function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Features Products </h1>
      <div className="products">
        {data.products.map((product) => (
          <div className="product" key={product.slug}>
            <a href={`/product/${product.slug}`}>
              <img src={product.image} alt={product.name} />
            </a>

            <div className="product-info">
              <a href={`/product/${product.slug}`}>
                <p>{product.name}</p>
              </a>
              <p>
                <strong>${product.price}</strong>
              </p>
              <button> Add To Cart</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

where can be the mistake? please help me

Comment: What is version of react router dom you are using. can you share you package.json. and also you said you are getting one error, what is that error can you share that too.? and if possible put in code sandbox that will be easy to help you out.

Comment: i have added the picture in the post

Comment: I see no issue with this specific code ***other than*** you should be importing and using the `Link` component instead of raw anchor `<a/>` tags. Are you sure you've all the project dependencies installed correctly? How are you running the app? How is this `App` component rendered? How is the app rendered to the DOM?

Comment: I doubt the issue would be reproducible, but could you try creating a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces this issue that we could inspect live?

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to break your App a bit, so it will be clearer what happens.

Layout that is same for all routes should be provided in toplevel route, not around `Routes`. `Outlet` inside `Layout` component will be replaced with particular route.

For more about `Outlet` check [official documentation](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/outlet), I warmly recommend this [tutorial](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial).

```
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter , Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';

function Layout() {
  return (
    <div>
      <header>
        <a href="/">VAC</a>
      </header>

      <main>
        <Outlet />
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      {/* Here we provide styles through Layout component. */}
      <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
        <Route index element={<HomeScreen />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
}

/* It's good idea to separate providers from App. */
function WrappedApp() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default WrappedApp;
```

If still nothing is displayed, please right click on webpage and in menu choose "inspect page source" and please provide what it shows. Additionaly it would also be useful to see `index.ts` file.

Comment: I have added the picture in the post.

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import App from "./components/App";

render(
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>,
  document.getElementById("app")
  
);

// App.js 
import React from "react";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import HomePage from "./home/HomePage";
import AboutPage from "./about/AboutPage";
import Header from "./common/Header";
import PageNotFound from "./PageNotFound";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="container-fluid">
      <Header />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
        <Route path="/about" component={AboutPage} />
        <Route component={PageNotFound} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```